# Injective modules over noncommutative noetherian rings

Tags: reference-request, modules, injective-modules, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a left noetherian ring, then it is well known that Matlis proved that any injective $R$-module decomposes into a sum of indecomposable injectives, each of form $E(R/I)$ for some irreducible left ideal $I$. If moreover $R$ is commutative, we know much more: indecomposable injectives correspond to prime ideals via $P \rightarrow E(R/P)$ and each $E(R/P)$ is filtered by vector spaces over quotient field of $R/P$, which makes it quite analogical to injective abelian groups in my eyes.

What is known in the non-commutative case? Is there also some nice filtration as in the commutative case?

Thanks in advance for any reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noncommutative analogue of this result is explained in Bo Stenstrom's *Rings of Quotients*, particularly in Chapter 7, “Hereditary Torsion Theories for Noetherian Rings”.

It's been a long time since I looked at this, so I forget the details, but my impression was that the noncommutative theory was not nearly as nice.

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems to be a very satisfactory source!